# Hibernate 6.1.1.Final - Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to use hibernate but I just can't get it to load.

This is the exception I am getting:

```
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlFile(ConfigLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:347)
    at net.craftanvil.bungeecore.Main.onEnable(Main.java:41)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:266)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:295)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:67)
    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 87; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:443)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:125)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 87; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2133)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:830)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:46)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement(StAXEventConnector.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:420)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my main class and my configuration file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
this.sessionFactory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
                .configure(new File(this.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + HIBERNATE_CONFIG_FILE_NAME))
                .addAnnotatedClass(PlayerData.class)
                //.setProperty("connection.url", config.getString("database.host"))
                //.setProperty("connection.username", config.getString("database.username"))
                //.setProperty("connection.password", config.getString("database.password"))
                .buildSessionFactory();
```

I've tried a a lot of solution either changing the config or the main class but... not of them worked.